# question about Functional dependancy

Tags: database-design, functional-dependencies

I have to find minimal cover for the following FD set,

AB -> D
D->B

I am not familiar with the finding cover, whether even is it possible or not?
what i feel tricky thing in above is kind of cyclic relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minimal cover of the above remains same